# Two way binding from the link function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Can someone tell me why I am not able to two way bind from the link function?

Please refer to this plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/RI1ztP?p=preview

The below watch successfully adds the collection to attrs.ngModel but I dont see it reflecting in the parent controller

```
scope.$watchCollection("selectedItems",function(collection){
    attrs.ngModel = [];
    for(var i=0;i<collection.length;i++){
      attrs.ngModel.push(collection[i]);
    }
    console.log("ngModel",attrs.ngModel);
  });
```

Cant see the collection over here (selectedUsers):

```
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
 <div multi-select-search-box ng-model="selectedUsers" label="name" my-options="state in states"></div>
{{selectedUsers}}
```

If you look at the above html, I am binding the selectedUsers array to ng-model. In my link function, i add the selected users to attrs.ngModel array. When I look at the console, the selectedUsers are added to attrs.ngModel but the array isn't reflected back on the html {{selectedUsers}}

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you eleborate?

Comment: added more info. please let me know @BasSlagter

Comment: attrs.ngModel is a string, you cannot push values in there like this.

Comment: how do i get the selectedUsers to bind then?

Comment: That push is working is only because your make it an array yourself (attrs.ngModel = [];) but that will not automatically reflect to the ngModel you specified.

Comment: If you can access the parent scope you can access selectedUsers through $scope.selectedUsers.

Comment: I dont want to do that because what if the user changes the array name, the whole component will break. I want this custom directive to be loosely coupled.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to require the ng-model controller and sync changes using the viewValue array:

```
scope.$watchCollection("selectedItems",function(collection){
    ctrl.$viewValue.splice(0,ctrl.$viewValue.length);
    for(var i=0;i<collection.length;i++){
      ctrl.$viewValue.push(collection[i]);
    }
  });
```

and

```
require: 'ngModel'
```

Answer (score 1):

The data bound to the `ng-model` of your `multi-select-search-box` is `$scope.selectedUsers`.

Therefore to register a change in the DOM you have to update that variable rather than `ng-model`.

```
scope.$watchCollection("selectedItems",function(collection){
  for(var i=0;i<collection.length;i++){
    scope.myNgModelVar.push(collection[i]);
  }
});
```

Since `ng-model` is a string that gets `$parse()/$eval()` called on it to evaluate it as an expression, updating that `ng-model` value won't do you any good.

#### EDIT:

After some clarification it appears that this is a custom directive designed to be reusable. So therefore we do not want to stick variables from your controller inside the directive. Instead, you should bind a directive attribute to your directives scope.

```
// Directive Def. Object:

return {
  restrict: "AE",
  scope: {
    myNgModelVar: "=",
    bindModel: "=ngModel" //This is the alternate method aliasing ngModel var with a scope var.
  },
  template: "<input ng-model='myNgModelVar' />"
};
```

Although you could use ngModel by using an alias `scope: {bindModel:'=ngModel'}`, this gives you an isolated scope variable that you bind to ngModel instead. Therefore keeping your directive reusable.

Comment: I do not want to use selectedUsers directly because if the user decides to use some other array, the whole component will break. I am designing this directive so that others can use it. Can I use attrs.ngModel to do it somehow?

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhh. Let me see if I can rework the answer so you can make this directive reusable.